# Can't read text file from assets (Android Studio,JAVA)

Tags: java, android

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

So the answer is what Henry said.
It's impossible to access assets from class which isn't an activity.
After passing AssetManager object as parameter from main activity, it works, a non-activity class method is able to read asset.
In my case:

```
AssetManager am = getAssets();
tc.ReadFile2(am);
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I have problem with reading .txt from assets directory. I tried almost everything, yet the result is always the same:

```
I/System.out: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

This is how looks directory tree of project:
[directory tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ku2rj.jpg)

I also tried to list assets, but result is same as above.
Here is current code of my class:

```
import  java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class TextChange extends AppCompatActivity {
public  TextChange(){}

protected String ReadFile() throws IOException{
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(context.getAssets().open("sampleText.txt")));
    String text = "";
    while (reader.readLine() != null){
        text = reader.readLine();
    }
    System.out.println(text);
    return text;
}

protected String ReadFile2() throws IOException{
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    InputStream input = getAssets().open("sampleText2.txt");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"));
    String str;

    while ((str=in.readLine()) != null) {
        buf.append(str);
    }

    in.close();

    return buf.toString();
}

public String[] ListAssets() throws IOException{
    AssetManager am = getAssets();
    String[] files = am.list("");
    for (String s : files) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    return files;
}
}
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong and how to fix this issue?
Any help is welcome!

printStackTrace:

```
W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException
W/System.err:     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getAssets(ContextWrapper.java:83)
W/System.err:     at jb.jbench.TextChange.ReadFile2(TextChange.java:28)
W/System.err:     at jb.jbench.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:43)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: On which line is the NullPointerException? Can you post the full StackTrace?

Comment: The full exception message will give you a specific line number that is throwing the Null Pointer Exception. If you can tell us which line in your code is being indicated by that error message we will probably be able to help you.

Comment: This class also seems to be an invalid implementation of an activity, as you do not have an `onCreate()` method, you do not have the `context` field that is referred to by the source, etc.

Comment: In main activity I create object of class, and call this method onClick action

Comment: `It's impossible to access assets from class which isn't an activity` what a nonsense is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot instantiate an `Activity` class yourself. Always let the system do that. Activities can only be started by using an `Intent`, otherwise important fields will not be properly initialized.

If you want to put the functionality into a separate class, don't extend `Activity` and pass in the needed context as a parameter.

Comment: However, I don't start any new activity. All I do in main activity is calling the method to read assets.

Comment: And this method calls `getAssets` which does not work because the `Activity` is not initialized.

Comment: So, if class is not an activity, just functional class doing some work, it can't get access to assets?

Comment: Only if you pass it as a parameter.

Comment: Therefore the solution would be to load assets in activity, and invoke method with needed asset?

Comment: No need to load it, just pass in the `AssetManager` and do the rest in the method.